# Why does the divs starts from between in case of overflow hidden?

Tags: html, css

> Styles

```
    body{
      margin:unset;
    }
    .carousel{
      height: 200px;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 10px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 50px 1fr 50px;
      grid-gap: 10px;
    }
    .carousel-controls{
      color: navy;
    }
    .carousel > div{
      display: grid;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    .carousel-holder{
      background: purple;
      display: grid;
      grid-gap: 10px;
      grid-auto-flow: column;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 10px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .carousel-cards{
      background: white;
      height: 100%;
      width: 125px;
      display: grid;
      place-items:center;
      font-weight: bolder;
      color: navy;
    }
```

> Markup with bit of php for card generation

```
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-controls carousel-controls-prev ">
      <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-holder">
      <?php
        $x = 1;
        while ($x <= 250) {
          echo "<div class='carousel-cards'>".$x."</div>";
          $x++;
        }
      ?>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-controls carousel-controls-next ">
      <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
```

> The result
> [image]

> Problem

I am making a carousel to which Ill add javascript later. Now my problem is that the generated cards which should start from 1 are actually starting from 120 when I am using overflow hidden.

Comment: You have the carousel aligned to center so it makes perfect sense that `<div class='carousel-cards'>125</div>` is loading in the center of the screen if you have 250 cards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards to your content centering, in your css, it should be justify-content:start and not justify-content:center.

So, it should look like this:

```
 .carousel > div{
      display: grid;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: start;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your alignment to left if you want it to start at 1 rather than the center using:

```
.carousel-cards{
    justify-content: left;
}
```

See it in action below:

```css
body{
      margin:unset;
    }
    .carousel{
      height: 200px;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 10px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 50px 1fr 50px;
      grid-gap: 10px;
    }
    .carousel-controls{
      color: navy;
    }
    .carousel > div{
      display: grid;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: left;
    }
    .carousel-holder{
      background: purple;
      display: grid;
      grid-gap: 10px;
      grid-auto-flow: column;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 10px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .carousel-cards{
      background: white;
      height: 100%;
      width: 125px;
      display: grid;
      place-items:center;
      font-weight: bolder;
      color: navy;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-controls carousel-controls-prev ">
      <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-holder">
      <div class='carousel-cards'>1</div>
      <div class='carousel-cards'>2</div>
      <div class='carousel-cards'>3</div>
      <div class='carousel-cards'>4</div>
      <div class='carousel-cards'>5</div>
      <div class='carousel-cards'>6</div>
      <div class='carousel-cards'>7</div>
      <div class='carousel-cards'>8</div>
      <div class='carousel-cards'>9</div>
      <div class='carousel-cards'>10</div>
      <div class='carousel-cards'>11</div>
      <div class='carousel-cards'>12</div>
      <div class='carousel-cards'>13</div>
      <div class='carousel-cards'>14</div>
      <div class='carousel-cards'>15</div>
      <div class='carousel-cards'>16</div>
      <div class='carousel-cards'>17</div>
      <div class='carousel-cards'>18</div>
      <div class='carousel-cards'>19</div>
      <div class='carousel-cards'>20</div>
      <div class='carousel-cards'>21</div>
      <div class='carousel-cards'>22</div>
      <div class='carousel-cards'>23</div>
      <div class='carousel-cards'>24</div>
      <div class='carousel-cards'>25</div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-controls carousel-controls-next ">
      <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
```